# COUNT() and Left Join not working

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, left-join

I'm having trouble at query which displays the Employee Number, First Name, Last Name and the number of orders of each employee. Make sure that the Number of orders column name should be “OrderCount”. Order By the OrderCount then by employee ID. Null is allowed.

employee_data containing columns: `Emp_ID`, `F_Name`, `L_Name`

order_data containing columns: `O_ID`,`Emp_ID`, `OrderNumber`

Here's my query:

```
Select order_data.Emp_ID, F_Name, L_Name, COUNT(employee_data.Emp_ID) as OrderCount
FROM order_data
LEFT JOIN employee_data
ON employee_data.Emp_ID = order_data.Emp_ID
GROUP BY order_data.Emp_ID
ORDER BY OrderCount
```

These are my tables:

employee_data
[image]

order_data

[image]

And the output should be:

[image]

But it is giving me this wrong input.

[image]

Comment: Whats the issue(SQL Error/Wrong result) you are getting ?

Comment: First: I assume that there exists no order without a customer assigned to it. If I am right, then you don't need to use LEFT JOIN. Just use JOIN since LEFT JOIN explicitly allows employee_data to be empty

Comment: I'm getting a wrong result. @AbdulManaf

Comment: Right Join but i'm still wrong @ITroubs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT od.Emp_ID, ed.F_Name, ed.L_Name, COUNT(DISTINCT od.O_ID) AS OrderCount
FROM order_data od 
LEFT JOIN employee_data ed ON ed.Emp_ID = od.Emp_ID
GROUP BY od.Emp_ID
ORDER BY OrderCount
```

Comment: It gives me no null but more zero results.

Comment: It worked thanks! I just modify the query a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate functions cannot be used along with other fields in a query.
You can use it in a sub-query, as follows:

```
Select order_data.Emp_ID, F_Name, L_Name, (select COUNT(employee_data.Emp_ID) from employee_data) as OrderCount
FROM order_data
LEFT JOIN employee_data
ON employee_data.Emp_ID = order_data.Emp_ID
GROUP BY order_data.Emp_ID
ORDER BY OrderCount
```

Hope it helps .. :)

Comment: Am i going to use join? Sorry I don't get it.

Comment: You are going to use a sub-query to get the count. count() is an aggregate function and you cannot select aggregate function with other fields as per SQL syntax. So to get the count, you use a sub-query. Updated my answer for your case to make it clear. :) 
P.S: If it works out, you can mark this answer as accepted .. :)

Comment: But the value of all `OrderCount` is giving me 21.  :)

Comment: isnt that you want? Count() will give the count of **all** the IDs in the table.
Now I think probably you are looking for row number. If that is the case, you will require `row_num`. Please be specific on the same .. :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace in your Query

`ORDER BY OrderCount`

To

`ORDER BY order_data.Emp_ID`

Your Problem Solved....

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the tables in the wrong order:

```
Select ed.Emp_ID, ed.F_Name, ed.L_Name, COUNT(od.Emp_ID) as OrderCount
FROM employee_data ed LEFT JOIN
     order_data od
     ON ed.Emp_ID = od.Emp_ID
GROUP BY ed.Emp_ID
ORDER BY OrderCount;
```

Presumably you want all employees, with counts of their employees.  In a properly maintained database, you shouldn't have invalid employee ids on the order table.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the columns in the group by clause which are not being used in any aggregate function. Try to add 'order_data.Emp_ID, F_Name, L_Name' these columns in group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, if you don't wanna have the NULL values and don't want to know the employees with no orders, you could use a join... if you need the orders for non existing employees (however this may work), use

```
SELECT
  od.Emp_ID, ed.F_Name, ed.L_Name, COUNT(od.Emp_ID) as OrderCount
FROM 
  order_data od
LEFT JOIN 
  employee_data ed ON ed.Emp_ID = od.Emp_ID
GROUP BY 
  od.Emp_ID
ORDER BY 
  OrderCount, od.Emp_ID
```

you were also missing the second ORDER BY value.